# Html to PDF to JPEG

Tags: php, imagick, mpdf

I am basically all the way there.  I am unsure how to push the temporary pdf object to imagick to generate and return the jpeg image.  Using mPDF's standard output(), I get the pdf rendered to the screen:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($output);

$img = new Imagick($mpdf->output());
$img->setResolution(300,300);
$img->resampleImage(150,150,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,1);
$img->resizeImage(512,700,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,0);
$img->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$img->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$img->writeImage ("test.jpeg");
```

Under this scenario I get the pdf outputed to the screen instead of a jpg image returned/created.  What is the proper way to pass the pdf into imagick?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need: `$mpdf->Output('temp/'.$filename.'.pdf','F');`

```
$mpdf->Output('temp/'.$filename.'.pdf','F');
$pdf_file = 'temp/'.$filename.'.pdf';
$savepath = 'temp/'.$filename.'.jpg';
$img = new imagick($pdf_file);
$img->setImageFormat('jpg');
$img->writeImage($savepath);
echo "<img src='temp/$filename.jpg' />";
```

http://phpform.net/pdf-to-image.php